# What kind of class template definition is this?

Tags: c++

```
template<class T> struct is_ref_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

It appears in the [possible implementation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/make_array) of `std::experimental::make_array`. The reason it looks odd to me is that the class name contains a template parameter list `<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` mentioning only one parameter, but that parameter is inside the template argument of the class (i.e. something has been elided).

Comment: This is called specialization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other related line from the page you linked to is:

```
template<class> struct is_ref_wrapper : std::false_type {};
```

This defines the generic template. The next line is a specialization.

```
template<class T> struct is_ref_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

When `is_ref_wrapper` is instantiated with a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` as the template parameter, the specialization is used.

Answer (score 2):

That lines goes in tandem with the one above it:

```
template<class> struct is_ref_wrapper : std::false_type {};
template<class T> struct is_ref_wrapper<std::reference_wrapper<T>> : std::true_type {};
```

The first line declares the (primary) template `is_ref_wrapper`. The second line declares a specialization, which will be chosen instead of the primary template if and only if the parameter matches `std::reference_wrapper<T>` for some `T`. Which is exactly the required behaviour.